# how can you check an individual binary digit in c++

Tags: c++, binary, flags

I apologize for being vague, but our teacher specifically told us to do so if we ask questions

I have 9 flags I want to store as an integer.
ie, `0b111111111` would be all of them tripped.

Right now I have an if statement adding to the int if it's tripped.
ie.

```
if (flag0=="tripped" && flag0=="hasn't been tripped before") flagInt += 1;

if (flag1=="tripped" && flag1=="hasn't been tripped before") flagInt += 2;

if (flag2=="tripped" && flag2=="hasn't been tripped before") flagInt += 4;
```

and so on,

I'm having difficulty writing the code to check if a flag has been tripped or not.
How could I do this?

edit: I've considered converting the integer to a string of it's binary representation, so I could just chck with brackets, but I have to do this for quite a bit of data, and that would make it too slow

Comment: Use binary `&` operator and a mask (e.g. 0b00000010 for flag1) to check if single bits are set (result is > 0 in case of a matching bit).

Answer (score 3):

To get bit `n` state (returns bit n as 0 or 1):

```
(value>>n) & 1
```

To set bit `n` state (flag is 0 or 1):

```
value = (value & ~(1 << n)) | (flag << n)
```

Comment: bool play::used(int flag,int a){
  int b = flag & a;
  if (flag == a) return true;
  return false;
}  thanks a lot, this is what I used.